# Step through K combinations algorithm X steps at a time

Tags: javascript, combinations, permutation

I have a function ([from Akseli Palén](https://gist.github.com/axelpale/3118596)) to calculate combinations of X elements in a given Array that looks like this.

```
function k_combinations(set, k) {
  var i, j, combs, head, tailcombs;
  if (k > set.length || k <= 0) { return []; }
  if (k == set.length) { return [set]; }
  if (k == 1) {
    combs = [];
    for (i = 0; i < set.length; i++) { combs.push([set[i]]); }
    return combs;
  }
  // Assert {1 < k < set.length}
  combs = [];
  for (i = 0; i < set.length - k + 1; i++) {
    head = set.slice(i, i+1);
    tailcombs = k_combinations(set.slice(i + 1), k - 1);
    for (j = 0; j < tailcombs.length; j++) {
      combs.push(head.concat(tailcombs[j]));
    }
  }
  return combs;
}
```

It works nicely but when given a large array and/or K value to work with it slows down to the point where the browser tries to stop the script for being unresponsive so what I'm wondering is is it possible to extend this function so it accepts a starting position and maximum number of results to return in one call?  That way I could do something like "Displaying results 20-30 out of 100,000".  There is a sample form at 
http://jsbin.com/ricabomofetu/1/edit?js,output if anyone wants to have a crack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
function k_combinations(set, k, start_combo, max_results) {
    if (start_combo.length !== k)
        throw new Error("Starting combination is not of length k!");
    var cur = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        var idx = set.indexOf(start_combo[i]);
        if (idx === -1)
            throw new Error(i + "th element of starting combination isn't in the set!");
        if (i > 0 && idx <= cur[i - 1])
            throw new Error("Elements of start_combo must be in sorted order!");
        cur.push(idx);
    }

    function subset_from_indices(subset) {
        var ret = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < subset.length; i++)
            ret.push(set[subset[i]]);
        return ret;
    }

    var n = set.length;
    var results = [subset_from_indices(cur)];
    while (results.length < max_results) {
        var inc_idx = k - 1;
        while (inc_idx >= 0 && cur[inc_idx] === n - k + inc_idx)
            inc_idx--;

        if (inc_idx < 0) // no more combinations
            return results

        cur[inc_idx]++;
        for (var i = inc_idx + 1; i < k; i++) {
            cur[i] = cur[i - 1] + 1;
        }
        results.push(subset_from_indices(cur));
    }
    return results;
}

console.log(k_combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3, [1, 3, 4], 4));
// [ [ 1, 3, 4 ], [ 1, 3, 5 ], [ 1, 4, 5 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ] ]
```